Error with join attributes by location (picks the adjacent polygon ID)
There are two shapefile layers in QGIS. I am trying to join attribute by location ID2 from shp1 to ID1 in shp2. The IDs may vary for the same location in the two shapefile. However, some IDs by location match and I am using those as reference for join attribute by location to check if this function works in a desired manner. I have tried multiple techniques "overlap", "intersect", "within", "touch", so on. But none of this is giving the desired results. For example for 1122 in ID1 the joined value is 16 but it should be 1122.
Why is this occurring and how can I overcome this?

Label formula used:
"ID1"  || '\n' || "ID2"


You had a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but your question is about QGIS so I have removed it.

Can you change the symbology to make it possible to see how the two layers overlap?

To avoid problems when joining attributes by location with two polygon layers:
1- Apply the “Point in polygons” tool to layer 1
2- Join the attributes of the resulting point layer to layer 2. Use the “Join Attributes by Location” tool with the “intersect” predicate.
